# Django custom permission framework

Tags: django

I need to make a custom permission framework that not only allows/forbids users but can also set how many objects can a user create of a given type.

For example I need to be able to set how many times a user can submit a new pizza order.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to just write it yourself. There are too many variations to make something like that generic without creating an inner platform. For example, is the maximum number of orders that a user submits a forever thing, or is it a rate (pizza orders per day)?  To find out how many orders were submitted by a user in a time period, you just need some filtering in your view function:

```
thisTimeYesterday = datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
if PizzaOrder.objects.filter(time_placed__gte=thisTimeYesterday, 
    user=request.user).count() >= 3:
    return HttpResponseForbidden("How much pizza do you need, anyway?")
```

If you're trying to enforce this in the admin (my rule of thumb: never let anyone outside strangling distance access the admin), you may be able to use [custom validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and wrote a package that manages those types complex permissions. You basically use a rules.py file to define all your app's logical rules and these can then be used throughout your project, from within templates to hooks on your views.

https://bitbucket.org/aashe/django-logical-rules

Here's a template example:

```
{% load logical_rules_tags %}
{% testrule user_can_edit_mymodel object request.user %}
    <p>You are the owner!</p>
{% endtestrule %}
```

And if you're extending django's generic class-based views:

```
class MyView(RulesMixin, DetailView):

    def update_logical_rules(self):
            super(MyView, self).update_logical_rules()
            self.add_logical_rule({
                    'name': 'user_can_edit_mymodel',
                    'param_callbacks':
                            [('get_request_user', 'get_object')],
            })
```

Comment: This now has extended documentation at [ReadTheDocs](http://django-logical-rules.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)